# Spring MongoTemplate is very slow for 50000 records from MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

We are trying to retrieve 50000 records from mongoDB using Spring MongoTemplate. It takes forever like 4 minutes.

We also have requirement for retrieving at least million records for processing in java. Is there a way to do this quickly?

Comment: Copied comment from @mayurkale - *Just like to uncover more information, Have you tried using and indexes on the collections? How many id fields are you using in your query, could you provide an example of the document and query you are using?*

Comment: There may be many reasons, huge documents, retrieved data size huge to transfer to client by network, db hosting memory shortage, not properly indexing, wrong aggregation, host configuration, number of connections using etc.